# C# - Constructors and Inheritance

Tags: inheritance, c#-3.0, constructor

I have two classes declared like this:

```
class Object1
{
    protected ulong guid;
    protected uint type;

    public Object1(ulong Guid, uint Type)
    {
        this.guid = Guid;
        this.type = Type
    }
    // other details omitted
}

class Object2 : Object1
{
    // details omitted
}
```

In the client code, I want to be able to create an instance of each object like this:

```
Object1 MyObject1 = new Object1(123456789, 555);
Object2 MyObject2 = new Object2(987654321, 111);
```

How can I get Object2 to use Object1's constructor like that?
Thankyou.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
class Object2 : Object1
{
   Object2(ulong l, uint i ) : base (l, i)
   {
   }
}
```

Comment: Could someone please explain why this must be done? I appreciate the answer!

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide a constructor with the same signature for Object2 and then call the base class's constructor:

```
class Object2 : Object1
{
    public Object2(ulong Guid, uint Type) : base(Guid, Type) {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Give Object2 a constructor like this:-

```
public Object2(ulong Guid, uint Type): base(Guid, Type)
```

Comment: blast... you have type faster than light speed to get an answer in first on this site! ;-)

Comment: No, you just have to stop the time while you're typing your answer. Easy.

Comment: There was only a two minute difference - that's 120 seconds.